# Convergence of a complex power series on boundary of disc of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I'm looking at the following power series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)(n+2) \cdots 2n}{n^n} z^n
$$
and I'm trying to find the region in $\mathbb C$ in which this power series converges. The ratio test can be used to show the radius of convergence is equal to $R = e/4$, but I'm having trouble seeing what happens on the boundary.

I believe (after some experimentation) that the sequence $a_n = \frac{(n+1)(n+2) \cdots 2n}{n^n} \left(\frac e 4\right)^n$ converges to something other than $0$ (according to WolframAlpha the limit is $\sqrt 2$), and if this is true, then when $|z| = e/4$, the terms of the above series fail to converge to $0$, so the series diverges. But I'm having trouble showing why this sequence does not converge to $0$; any time I try comparing it to a smaller sequence I end up with a sequence that converges to $0$, which doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) one gets
$$
a_n =  \frac{(2n)!}{n! n^n} \left(\frac e 4\right)^n
\sim \frac{\sqrt{4 \pi n}\left(\frac {2n} e\right)^{2n}}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac {n} e\right)^{n} n^n} \left(\frac e 4\right)^n = \sqrt 2 
$$
so that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \sqrt 2 \ne 0$. It follows that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)(n+2) \cdots 2n}{n^n} z^n
$$
does not converge on the boundary of the disk of convergence, as you conjectured.